# Prove that $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}]$ does not equal $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Prove that $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}]$ does not equal $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}]$.

This is homework. I want to prove that these are different sets. The first set is the smallest ring containing the integers and the two radicals separately. The second is the smallest ring containing the integers and the sum of the two radicals. Unfortunately I cannot find any similar proofs to learn from. I've been trying to show that the second set does not contain the square roof of $6$, for instance, or the square root of $3$. We haven't looked at what the second set might contain. We've only looked at adjoining a single radical and not the sum of radicals on class.  If someone could solve a similar example or give me a crucial insight, that would be great.

Comment: Is $\sqrt 2$ a member of one set and not another?

Comment: I suppose that root 2 is not in the second set, since that would imply that root 3 was and thus that the sets are equal. But it's not clear to me how to prove this.

Comment: Can you describe the elements of the second ring?

Comment: Honestly, no. We simply have not been taught how to do so. Of course I know that all sums and products are involved. But I don't know how to shape the chaos. With just root 2 adjoined, I could do so.  Playing around with sums and products, it seems that one cannot isolate root 2 or root 3 or root 6. But I can't formalize this, only conjecture.

Comment: Well, you seem to know what the elements of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt2+\sqrt3)$ are... Maybe a similar idea works?

Comment: Let's start with: what is the definition of the second ring?

Comment: Surely, both sets contain $\sqrt2+\sqrt3$ and all its powers. I suggest that you write out the first few powers of this number, simplifying appropriately, of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint** $\ $ Note $\,\ \sqrt{3}\,\not\in \Bbb Z[\alpha]\ $ for  $\ \alpha\, =\, \sqrt 3 +\! \sqrt{2}\ $  of degree $\,4\,$ over $\Bbb Q,\,$ else
$$\!\!\!\! \begin{eqnarray}
\alpha\,(2\sqrt 3-\!\alpha)&=&\phantom{._{I^{I^I}}}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\! (\sqrt 3+\!\sqrt 2)(\sqrt 3-\!\sqrt 2)\, =\, \color{#0a0}{1}\\
\Rightarrow\ \  \alpha\sqrt 3\,  =\, \dfrac{\alpha^2}{\color{#c00}2}\!&+&\!\dfrac{\color{#0a0}{1}}2\,\in\,\color{}{\Bbb Z}[\alpha]\, =\,\color{}{\Bbb Z}\!+\!\alpha\Bbb Z\!+\!\color{}{\alpha^2{\color{#c00}{\Bbb Z}}}\!+\!\alpha^3\Bbb Z \,\ \Rightarrow\ \dfrac{1}{\color{#c00}2} \in \color{#c00}{\Bbb Z}\end{eqnarray}$$

Comment: The same argument works for $\,\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b},\ $ see [this answer.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/641633/242)

Comment: We haven't talked about degrees, but this proof is terse and gives me the kind of contradiction I was hoping for. Thanks.

Comment: @s.z. There is further discussion in the comments of the linked generalization which may prove helpful in that regard.

Comment: For your description of the ring you need more than knowing that a is of degree four over the rationals.

Comment: This is quite violently unmotivated.

Comment: @Mariano It's a hint / sketch. As I remarked, if the OP needs further details they are in the linked comments - which address your first remark.

Comment: But why would anyone compute $a(2\sqrt3-a)$?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: Conjugating $\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{2}$ seems like a natural thing to do, and then trying to express the conjugate $\sqrt{3} - \sqrt{2}$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-linear combination of $\sqrt{3}$ and $\alpha$ makes sense. Solving $\sqrt{3} - \sqrt{2} = m\alpha + n\sqrt{3}$ yields $m=-1$, $n=2$.

Comment: @Bungo, and the answer would go from an opaque *verification* to an instructive example on how to deal with these things if it explain that. That is my point.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: I agree with your point. This answer (even as a hint) is a bit cryptic as written.

Comment: @Bungo Alas, I don't think there is a nice way to adequately explain what is going on here without employing more advanced concepts from algebraic number theory.

Answer (score 3):

Not the most elegant solution, but note that
$$(\sqrt2+\sqrt3)^{2n+1}=a_n\sqrt2+b_n\sqrt3,$$
where $a_0=b_0=1$ and
$$(\sqrt2+\sqrt3)^2(a_n\sqrt2+b_n\sqrt3)=(5+\sqrt6)(a_n\sqrt2+b_n\sqrt3)=(5a_n+6b_n)\sqrt2+(5b_n+4a_n)\sqrt3,$$
so
$$2\mid a_{n+1}-b_{n+1}\iff 2\mid(5a_n+6b_n)-(5b_n+4a_n)=a_n-b_n+2b_n.$$

Therefore the difference $a_n-b_n$ is even for all $n$. Even powers $(\sqrt2+\sqrt3)^{2n}$ contain just $\sqrt6$. But the elements of $\mathbb Z[\sqrt2+\sqrt3]$ have the form
$$\sum_{k=0}^d z_k(\sqrt2+\sqrt3)^k.$$
This means the difference of multiples of $\sqrt2$ and $\sqrt3$ always has to be even, which contradicts $\sqrt2$ or $\sqrt3$ being elements of this ring.

I obviously assume we already know $\sqrt2, \sqrt3$ and $\sqrt6$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Right you are. I find nothing inelegant in this.

Comment: @Lubin I'm sure there's some slick argument why the difference is even and I missed it.

Comment: Write down the first, second, and third powers of $\sqrt2+\sqrt3$ and observe that the fourth power is a $\Bbb Z$-linear conmbination of $1$ and these three numbers.

Comment: Thanks for your help. We haven't talked out things being "over Q" yet. We've just learned the definition of IDs and fields. The approach to these added elements was just a sketch.