# Find $\alpha$ such that the given field is $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

This question is in regards to separable field extensions. I am to show that this $\alpha$ is in the given field and verify by direct computation that the given generators for the extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ can indeed by expressed as formal polynomials in $\alpha$ with coefficient in $\mathbb{Q}$.

For $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2, \sqrt3)$, the given answer is as follows :

"We try $\alpha = \sqrt2 + \sqrt3$. Squaring and cubing, we find $\alpha^2 = 5 + 2\sqrt2\sqrt3$ and $\alpha^3 = 11\sqrt2 + 9\sqrt3$.

Because $\sqrt2 = \frac{\alpha^3 - 9\alpha}{2}$ and $\sqrt3 = \frac{11\alpha - 9\alpha^3}{2}$, we see that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2 + \sqrt3)$ = $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2, \sqrt3)$"

I'm trying to understand the logical jump from knowing the $\alpha^2$ and $\alpha^3$ to the value of $\sqrt2 = \frac{\alpha^3 - 9\alpha}{2}$ and $\sqrt3 = \frac{11\alpha - 9\alpha^3}{2}$. Also, how is this relevant to the question and separable fields?

Thank you in advance.

(It isn't a duplicate, I believe. I'm trying to draw a connection between $\alpha^2$ and why $\alpha^3$ was even used in the first place when the the irreducible is of degree 2.)

Comment: Also, every separable finite degree field extension has a primitive element $\alpha$, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem).

Comment: It isn't a duplicate, I believe. I'm trying to draw a connection between $\alpha^2$ and why $\alpha^3$ was even used in the first place when the the irreducible is of degree 2.

Comment: We know that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$. We need to show the other way containment too for which it is enough to show $\sqrt{2} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}) $ and also for $\sqrt{3}$. By expressing each of these element as a polynomial expression in $\alpha$,we see that indeed both of these elements lie in the required field.

Comment: I agree, not a duplicate. You are trying to understand a particular proof you read, but the answers to http://math.stackexchange.com/q/93463/139123 use different proofs. However, you should still look at them, as they show a different insight.

Comment: Thanks a lot, David. I did go through several of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general principle is this: if $K \supseteq F$ are fields and $\alpha\in K$ then $F(\alpha) \subseteq K$, because $F(\alpha)$ is the *smallest* field containing $F$ and $\alpha$.

So, since $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$ contains both $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$, it contains their sum, so it contains $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})$.

To show the other inclusion, it follows from the "general principle" (and the fact that $F(\alpha, \beta) = F(\alpha)(\beta)$) that it suffices to show that $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$ are elements of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})$. Letting $\alpha = \sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$, we seek to express $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$ as rational functions of $\alpha$. We compute its powers, starting with $$\alpha^2 = 5+2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{3}.$$
We can't isolate either surd from this so we go on to $$\alpha^3 = 11\sqrt{2} + 9\sqrt{3}.$$
Look! That has $11$ root twos in it. So $$\alpha^3 - 11\alpha = -2\sqrt{3}$$
from which we obtain the expression for $\sqrt{3}$. Similarly, $$\alpha^3 - 9\alpha = 2\sqrt{2}.$$