# Show $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ is a simple extension field of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> Show $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ is a simple extension field of $\mathbb{Q}$.

---

Since $\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}\in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$, and $\sqrt{2}\sqrt{3}=\sqrt{6}\in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$, so $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6})$, hence $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ is a simple extension field of $\mathbb{Q}$.

---

Does my argument right? The only information I have is : A field extension $E$ of $F$ is called a simple extension if $E = F(\alpha)$ for some $\alpha \in E$.

Comment: The answers given are correct but there is the primitive element theorem which states that for any field $F$ of characteristic $0$ and any finite extension $E/F$ of $F$ you can find $\alpha\in E$ such that $E=F(\alpha)$. Hence any finite extension over $\mathbb{Q}$ is simple.

Answer (score 5):

Definition: $\def\Q{{\Bbb Q}}\Q(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots)$ is the smallest field containing $\Q$ and $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots\,$.

Lemma: $\Q(\sqrt2,\sqrt3)=\Q(\sqrt2+\sqrt3)$.

Proof.  By definition, LHS is a field which contains $\sqrt2$ and $\sqrt3$.  Since a field is closed under addition, LHS is a field containing $\Q$ and $\sqrt2+\sqrt3$.  By definition, RHS is the smallest such field, so RHS${}\subseteq{}$LHS.

By definition, RHS is a field containing $\Q$ and $\alpha=\sqrt2+\sqrt3$.  By the closure laws, RHS also contains the following:

- $\alpha^3=11\sqrt2+9\sqrt3$;
- $\alpha^3-9\alpha=2\sqrt2$;
- $\frac12(\alpha^3-9\alpha)=\sqrt2$;
- $\alpha-\sqrt2=\sqrt3$.

That is, RHS is a field containing $\Q$ and $\sqrt2$ and $\sqrt3$, so RHS${}\supseteq{}$LHS.

Hence $\Q(\sqrt2,\sqrt3)=\Q(\sqrt2+\sqrt3)$, and this is a simple extension.

Comment: Therefore $ \mathbb Q( \sqrt2, \sqrt3): \mathbb Q$ is simple. (I think this is the missing conclusion of the proof, isn't? )

Answer (score 2):

No, your argument is not correct: just because $\sqrt{6}$ is an element of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$, does not mean that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6})$. In fact
$$[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}):\mathbb{Q}]=4\quad\qquad [\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6}):\mathbb{Q}]=2$$
However, you will find this thread relevant: [Is $\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}) = \mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/93463)

Comment: $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}\in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$, I may need to write a argument for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})$, right?

Comment: Indeed, you will need an argument. After all, $0$ is an element of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$, that doesn't mean $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})=\mathbb{Q}(0)=\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @Simple since $\sqrt2+\sqrt3\in \Bbb Q(\sqrt2,\sqrt3)$, we have $\Bbb Q(\sqrt2+\sqrt3)\subseteq \Bbb Q(\sqrt2,\sqrt3)$. You also need to prove inclusion the other way, either by constructing $\sqrt2$ and $\sqrt3$ inside $\Bbb Q(\sqrt2+\sqrt3)$, or by a more abstract argument, like extension degrees.

Comment: Do  I need show $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})$ is a field?