# I want know if my logic in showing that $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3) = \Bbb Q (\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3)$ is correct

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, extension-field

I want to know if my logic in showing that $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3) = \Bbb Q (\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3)$ is correct

Now firstly, it seems that $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3)=(\Bbb  Q (\sqrt 2))(\sqrt3){\overset{{\huge\color\red?}}{=}}\{a+b\sqrt2+c\sqrt 3:a,b,c\in \Bbb Q\}$

But from my last question it seems that we need to check this for multiplicative closure, $(a+b\sqrt2 + c\sqrt3)(d+e\sqrt 2 + f\sqrt 3)=ad+ae\sqrt 2+ af\sqrt 3 + 2eb+bf\sqrt 3+cd\sqrt 3+ ce\sqrt2\sqrt3+ 3cf$

> So we actually find I believe that:
>
> $\Bbb Q(\sqrt2,\sqrt3)=\{a+b\sqrt 2+c\sqrt 3+ d\sqrt2\sqrt3:a,b,c,d\in \Bbb Q\}$?

---

I believe that $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2 +\sqrt 3)\overset{\huge{\color\red ?}}=\{a+b(\sqrt 2+ \sqrt 3):a,b\in \Bbb Q\}$

So let's verify multiplicative closure $(a+b\sqrt 2+ b\sqrt 3)(c+d\sqrt 2+ d\sqrt 3)$

$$=ac+ad\sqrt 2+ad\sqrt 3+bc\sqrt2+2bd+bd\sqrt3+bc\sqrt3+bd\sqrt2\sqrt3+3bd$$
$$=(ac+3bd+2bd)+(ad+bc)\sqrt 2 + (ad+bd+bc)\sqrt 3 +(bd)\sqrt2\sqrt3$$

> Since $\sqrt2$ and $\sqrt 3$ and $\sqrt2\sqrt3$ don't share common coefficients, they are linearly independent and hence $\Bbb Q(\sqrt2+\sqrt 3)=\Bbb Q(\sqrt2,\sqrt3)$(from above, i.e we have deduced that:) $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})=\{a+b\sqrt2+c\sqrt3:a,b,c\in\Bbb Q\}$.

---

Is that the correct way to show this? Also this means we have:

$$\begin{matrix}&&\left(\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})=\Bbb Q(\sqrt2,\sqrt3)\right)\\\\&{\huge\diagup}&&{\huge\diagdown}\\\Bbb Q(\sqrt2)&&&&\Bbb Q(\sqrt 3)\end{matrix}$$

Comment: Where is $\sqrt6=\sqrt 2 \sqrt 3$ ?

Comment: @lhf Sorry it's really long, just before the first line break thing, I add that from the deductions

Comment: You might be interested in [this question and its answers](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93463/is-mathbfq-sqrt2-sqrt3-mathbfq-sqrt2-sqrt3?rq=1).

Comment: @lhf I added boxes for the main points

Comment: @Pierre-GuyPlamondon It's a good set of answers and I'm reading them now, but I am interested in seeing where my logic is wrong, or my 'deduction' might need tweaking, hopefully someone can read it all lol

Comment: Your first belief is right but your second belief is not because the set given is not closed under multiplication.

Comment: Your answer seems to indicate that $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ has dimension $4$ over $\Bbb Q$ (this is true), but that $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3})$ has dimension $2$ (this is false). Your proof of "closure" in $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3})$ is flawed, do you see why?

Comment: @DavidWheeler Oh sorry I should have wrote that out more, I saw that all 4 parts have different coefficients, and thought they must be linearly independent and just concluded that they are equal(to the above construction)

Comment: But since there is a $\sqrt2\sqrt3$ term, your multiplication is not closed.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Oh man I just realised how non-transparent my red questionmark notation thing was, I'll edit it again. I solved the problem in a 'operation' way unfortunately that's not very good communication sorry. I was trying to show that the naive guess leads to needing to throw more things into the mix.

Comment: I think I understand what you are trying to do, but your conclusion of the linear independence of $1,\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}$,and $\sqrt{6}$ in your expanded product of two elements of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3})$ still has big "gaps" in it, and you still need to address the issue of whether or not  $1,\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}$,and $\sqrt{6}$ *span* $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3})$. Another possible approach would be to actually determine the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}$ over $\Bbb Q$.

Answer (score 5):

The "usual" proof that $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}) \subseteq \Bbb Q(\sqrt{2}+ \sqrt{3})$ ), the other inclusion is obvious.

It suffices to show that $\sqrt{2} \in \Bbb Q(\sqrt{2}+ \sqrt{3})$, since then $\sqrt{3} = (\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}) - \sqrt{2}$ must be as well.

Now $(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3})^3 = 2\sqrt{2} + 6\sqrt{3} + 9\sqrt{2} + 3\sqrt{3}$

$= 11\sqrt{2} + 9\sqrt{3}$.

Hence $\dfrac{1}{2}[(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3})^3 - 9(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3})] = \sqrt{2}$, QED.

Comment: Not wrong, of course, and I had a similar answer, but actually Plamondon's link above in comments give an answer by Rudy the Reindeer that is far, far simpler than both yours and mine. Pedro Tamaroff's answer below is basically the same simple solution. Besides, and that's why I removed my answer, it does not answer the OP's question at all.

Comment: One of the things that makes this such a good question is there exists a variety of ways to "solve it". I make no claim to my answer being "easier" or "simpler" than another, it is just very common. I like Pedro's answer for its pithiness :).

Comment: Thanks, this and Pedros hint are very clear after some thought

Answer (score 5):

Your belief that
$$\def\Q{\mathbb{Q}}
\Q(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})=\{a+b(\sqrt{2}+ \sqrt{3}):a,b\in \Q\}
$$
is wrong, as well as
$$
\Q(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})=\{a+b\sqrt{2}+ c\sqrt{3}:a,b,c\in \Q\}
$$
The second claim can be immediately dismissed, because this would mean that $[\Q(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}):\Q]=3$, but clearly $\Q(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})\subseteq\Q(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})]$ and this extension has degree a divisor of $4$, because
$$
[\Q(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}):\Q]=
[\Q(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}):\Q(\sqrt{2})]\,
[\Q(\sqrt{2}):\Q]
$$
and both extensions in the right-hand side are of degree either $1$ or $2$ (both $2$, actually, but it's not important).

The first belief is wrong, too: this would mean that $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ has a degree two minimal polynomial and this contradicts the fact you have to prove. Indeed
$$
[\Q(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}):\Q(\sqrt{2})]=2
$$
because no element of $\Q(\sqrt{2})$ is the square root of $3$:
$$
(a+b\sqrt{2})^2=3
$$
means
$$
a^2+2b^2+2ab\sqrt{2}=3
$$
hence either $a=0$ or $b=0$, leaving either $2b^2=3$ or $a^2=3$; neither equation has a solution in $\Q$.

Now *this* is a proof that $\Q(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})=\Q(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$. Indeed, we know that $[\Q(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}):\Q]=4$ and that
$$
[\Q(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}):\Q]>2
$$
(well, assuming we know that $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ is not rational, which is almost obvious). Therefore $[\Q(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}):\Q]$ is a divisor of $4$, but greater than $2$, which leaves just one possibility.

---

Why doesn't $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ have degree $\le2$ over $\Q$? Since $(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})^2=5+2\sqrt{6}$, we see that
$$
\Q\subset\Q(\sqrt{6})\subseteq\Q(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})
$$
and, since $\sqrt{6}$ is clearly irrational (a standard proof based on Eisenstein's criterion applies), we have that the degree of $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ (which we already know is a divisor of $4$) can be either $2$ or $4$. If it is $2$, we find that $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}=a+b\sqrt{6}$, for some $a,b\in\Q$. Squaring gives
$$
5+2\sqrt{6}=a^2+6b^2+2ab\sqrt{6}
$$
that implies $ab=1$, so
$$
a^2+\frac{6}{a^2}-5=0
$$
that is,
$$
a^4-5a^2+6=0
$$
or
$$
(a^2-2)(a^2-3)=0
$$
a contradiction.

---

Of course, the above is much more complicated than the direct observation that
$$
(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})+(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})^{-1}=
\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2}}=
\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}=2\sqrt{3}
$$
so $\sqrt{3}\in\Q(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})$ and therefore also $\sqrt{2}\in\Q(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})$, ending the proof. However, the main object was to show the issues in your argument.

Comment: I like this answer. It explains misconceptions of OP well and if it would contain a proof that minimal polynomial has to have degree greater than $2$, it would be perfect. Why am I expressing this? Because I feel this might actually be harder than proving $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3) = \mathbb Q(\sqrt 2, \sqrt 3)$ by inclusion of generators as in answer by David Wheeler and drawing conclusions about minimal polynomial after.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer, very helpful!

Answer (score 3):

Let $x=\sqrt 2+\sqrt 3$. Evaluate $\frac{x+x^{-1}}2$.

Comment: Proves that they don't share a coefficient? $\frac{\sqrt2 +\sqrt 3 + \sqrt 3 - \sqrt 2}{2}=\sqrt3 $ Oh your hint + the linked question make sense, thanks

Comment: @Understand No, proof that $\sqrt{3}$ is in $\Bbb Q(\sqrt2 +\sqrt3)$.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to completeness of the other answers let me find minimal polynomial of $\alpha = \sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3$ over $\mathbb Q$ directly.

\begin{align}
\alpha = \sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3 &\implies \alpha - \sqrt 2 = \sqrt 3\\
&\implies \alpha^2 -2\alpha\sqrt 2 + 2 = 3\\
&\implies \alpha^2 - 1 = 2\alpha\sqrt 2\\
&\implies \alpha^4 - 2\alpha^2 + 1 = 8\alpha^2\\
&\implies \alpha^4 - 10\alpha^2 + 1 = 0
\end{align}

Thus, $\alpha$ is a root of $p(x) = x^4 - 10x^2 + 1$, so if we show that it is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$, it will follow that it is minimal polynomial. By [Gauss's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss's_lemma_%28polynomial%29), since $p$ is primitive, it is enough to prove that it is irreducible over $\mathbb Z$. Assume the contrary, that $p = fg$ for non-invertible $f, g\in\mathbb Z[x]$. Neither $f$ nor $g$ can be of degree $0$ since $p$ is primitive, nor of degree $1$ since $p$ has no rational roots by [Rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem). So we have $\deg f = \deg g = 2$ and thus can write $$ p(x) = (x^2 + ax + b)(x^2 + cx + d),\quad a,b,c,d\in\mathbb Z $$ By expanding we get $$x^4 - 10x^2 + 1 = x^4 + (a+c)x^3 + (b+d+ac)x^2 + (ad + bc)x + bd$$ or equivalently

\begin{align}
a + c &= 0\\
b + d + ac &= -10\\
ad + bc &= 0\\
bd &= 1
\end{align}

Now, we note that $b = d = \pm 1$ and that neither cases yield integer solutions of above system and thus arrive at contradiction that $p$ is reducible.

Comment: Can't we just take $p(x) = x^4-10x^2 +1$ and apply rational root theorem directly? We get roots $\pm1 $ which both fail, hence irreducible?

Comment: @Understand, that's how I used the theorem, but you cannot conclude $p$ is irreducible just from that. It is enough to show that $p$ cannot be decomposed to product of polynomials of degree $1$ and $3$, but $p$ could still be product of two polynomials of degree $2$, and we need to consider that case as well.